# Type GridViewRow is not defined vb.net

Tags: vb.net, types, datagridview, grouping, defined

I want to group datagridview columns, So I've found this code but it give me error:

**"Type GridViewRow is not defined"**

What's wrong there?

```
Protected Sub OnDataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For i As Integer = SearchInvoiceDGV.Rows.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
        Dim row As GridViewRow = SearchInvoiceDGV.Rows(i)
        Dim previousRow As GridViewRow = SearchInvoiceDGV.Rows(i - 1)
        For j As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
            If row.Cells(j).Text = previousRow.Cells(j).Text Then
                If previousRow.Cells(j).RowSpan = 0 Then
                    If row.Cells(j).RowSpan = 0 Then
                        previousRow.Cells(j).RowSpan += 2
                    Else
                        previousRow.Cells(j).RowSpan = row.Cells(j).RowSpan + 1
                    End If
                    row.Cells(j).Visible = False
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Because this is not code for a `DataGridView` control. The WebControl `DataView` and the WinForms `DataGridView` are two different things.

Comment: @dr.null, you meant `GridView` rather than `DataView`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ah Exactly, thank you.